# Firebase. Stripe. How to check a particular user on paid subscription?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, stripe-payments

Currently, I can check only current user on paid subscription using:

```
import { auth } from "../../firebase";

export async function isUserPremium() {
    await auth.currentUser?.getIdToken(true)

    const decodedToken = await auth.currentUser?.getIdTokenResult()

    return decodedToken?.claims?.stripeRole ? true : false;
}
```

But I want to check particular one, if I have his **email** and **uid**, is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a Stripe customer ID, you can list all subscriptions for that customer like this:

```js
const subscriptions = await stripe.subscriptions.list({
  customer: "cus_xxx",
});
```

If you only have the customer email, then you first need to retrieve the customer (see code below) and then list all subscriptions for that customer (see code above).

```js
const customers = await stripe.customers.list({
  email: "foo@bar.com",
});
```

Comment: Okay... But where I should write this? In firebase functions?

Comment: Aha... Looks like works)) Thank you!